# How can I execute a method every year using BackgroundService in ASP.NET core Application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, background-service

```
     public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         { 
             var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
             var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
             while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                  foreach(var x in context.Students.ToList())
                  {
                   x.Class ++;
                   context.Students.Update(x);
                  } 
                     context.SaveChanges();
                     await Task.Delay(1000);
                 }
        }
```

I want to increase class of student By 1 every year. I want to execute this method automatically every new year,

Comment: in which kind of server you want to host this?

Comment: Coravel task scheduler is easy to use and get started with. It uses .NET Core hosted services under the covers, so no need to install anything other than the package. Since it's .NET native, not a port from an existing library for .NET Framework, it hooks into DI, etc:  https://github.com/jamesmh/coravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to my reply in this thread:
[How to trigger .NET Core 3.1 Hosted Service at certain time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005363/how-to-trigger-net-core-3-1-hosted-service-at-certain-time/64011649#64011649)

*If you want to implement scheduled tasks, I suggest you could also try to use the [Cronos](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cronos) package  and the [Cron Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) to configure the scheduled task (reference: [link](https://codeburst.io/schedule-cron-jobs-using-hostedservice-in-asp-net-core-e17c47ba06)).*

*The Cronos package is a lightweight but full-fledged library for parsing cron expressions and calculating next occurrences with time zones and daylight saving time in mind. The Cronos is an open source project sponsored by HangfireIO, and you can read detailed documentation from [its GitHub repository](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos).
The details steps as below:*

1. Install the [Cronos](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cronos) package via NuGet.
2. Create a CronJobService service with the following code:

   ```
    public abstract class CronJobService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        private readonly CronExpression _expression;
        private readonly TimeZoneInfo _timeZoneInfo;

        protected CronJobService(string cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo)
        {
            _expression = CronExpression.Parse(cronExpression);
            _timeZoneInfo = timeZoneInfo;
        }

        public virtual async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await ScheduleJob(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected virtual async Task ScheduleJob(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var next = _expression.GetNextOccurrence(DateTimeOffset.Now, _timeZoneInfo);
            if (next.HasValue)
            {
                var delay = next.Value - DateTimeOffset.Now;
                if (delay.TotalMilliseconds <= 0)   // prevent non-positive values from being passed into Timer
                {
                    await ScheduleJob(cancellationToken);
                }
                _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(delay.TotalMilliseconds);
                _timer.Elapsed += async (sender, args) =>
                {
                    _timer.Dispose();  // reset and dispose timer
                    _timer = null;

                    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        await DoWork(cancellationToken);
                    }

                    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        await ScheduleJob(cancellationToken);    // reschedule next
                    }
                };
                _timer.Start();
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public virtual async Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);  // do the work
        }

        public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _timer?.Stop();
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public interface IScheduleConfig<T>
    {
        string CronExpression { get; set; }
        TimeZoneInfo TimeZoneInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class ScheduleConfig<T> : IScheduleConfig<T>
    {
        public string CronExpression { get; set; }
        public TimeZoneInfo TimeZoneInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public static class ScheduledServiceExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddCronJob<T>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IScheduleConfig<T>> options) where T : CronJobService
        {
            if (options == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options), @"Please provide Schedule Configurations.");
            }
            var config = new ScheduleConfig<T>();
            options.Invoke(config);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(config.CronExpression))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ScheduleConfig<T>.CronExpression), @"Empty Cron Expression is not allowed.");
            }

            services.AddSingleton<IScheduleConfig<T>>(config);
            services.AddHostedService<T>();
            return services;
        }
    }
   ```
3. create a ScheduleJob.cs:

   ```
    public class ScheduleJob: CronJobService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ScheduleJob> _logger;

        public ScheduleJob(IScheduleConfig<ScheduleJob> config, ILogger<ScheduleJob> logger)
            : base(config.CronExpression, config.TimeZoneInfo)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ScheduleJob starts.");
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss} ScheduleJob is working.");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ScheduleJob is stopping.");
            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
   ```
4. Register the ScheduleJob service in the ConfigureServices method.

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHostedService<HelloWorldHostedService>(); 

        services.AddCronJob<ScheduleJob>(c=>
        {
            c.TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
            c.CronExpression = @"25 21 * * *"; // 21:25 PM daily.
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
   ```

   Then the result as below:

   [image]

In the above sample, it will run the Schedule Job at 21:25 PM daily. You can change the CronExpression to `0 0 1 1 *`, then, the job will run once a year at midnight of 1 January.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more architectural question rather than a coding question. There are several ways to achieve this. Hangfire is the easiest among them:

1.[**Hangfire**](https://www.hangfire.io/)

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() =>{
  foreach(var x in context.Students.ToList()) {
    x.Class++;
    context.Students.Update(x);
  }
  context.SaveChanges();
},
Cron.Yearly);
```

check their documentation to maintain(edit/delete/add) recurring jobs

2.**Ubuntu Cron Job**

Add a .net core console app and set it as a cron job of your ubuntu server https://ermir.net/topic-2/execute-net-core-console-application-as-an-ubuntu-cron-job

3.**Windows Service Task Scheduler**

If you are using windows server as hosting you can see this : https://medium.com/better-programming/asp-net-core-windows-service-task-scheduler-daily-weekly-monthly-700a569d502a

or just make your .net core to an exe file and follow this https://superuser.com/questions/239427/setting-an-annual-task-on-windows-task-scheduler?rq=1

4. **Cloud hosted functions**

You can use cloud functions such like Azure functions or Amazon lambda to run recurring/scheduled jobs/tasks
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-tutorial.html